# Find the CSRF token from head tag in htlm using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

HTML looks like this:

```
<head csrf-token="eCUDIDdtOwAHTgR4WE9ZWydwIAYvKQYIFRtXKWw7Nn4=...">
```

I was trying to extract this way:

```
token = soup.find('input', {'name':'csrfToken'})['value']
```

I keep getting:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

How to extract this token?

Answer (score 1):

Your tag is `head` not `input`, so adjust your selection and to get the value of the attribute, use its name:

```
soup.find('head')['csrf-token']
```

or with `css selectors`

```
soup.select_one('head')['csrf-token']
```

Output:

```
eCUDIDdtOwAHTgR4WE9ZWydwIAYvKQYIFRtXKWw7Nn4=...
```